# How to configure telegram online account from kde system settings

Tags: kubuntu, telegram, kde-telepathy

I'm using kubuntu and whenever I try to configure a telegram online account I get the message:

> This IM Account cannot be created - a Telepathy Connection Manager
>   named 'morse' is missing or it cannot handle protocol 'telegram'.
>   Please try installing morse with your package manager.

How can I install that? or alternatively, how can I configure the account?

Comment: From [Kubuntu release plan](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/Kubuntu): `Telepathy instant messaging client has been dropped from our defaults as it is no longer maintained upstream, and it has numerous issues. This is still available in the archive to install.` Yet I have [filed a bug](https://github.com/TelepathyIM/telepathy-morse/issues/57)

Comment: This [information](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ktp-contact-list/+bug/1512135) is relevant although fishy according to software standards. Use at your own.